# AngularJS ng-repeat input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make comments functionality using Angular js. The problem is that when i want to write a comment for a post, the text is also writing inside other input elements (comments). I write a text inside one input, but it writes it in all inputs

So for example same is happening with this code

```
<div class="comments" ng-repeat="articles in [1,2,[4,5,6]]">
<div ng-repeat="comments in articles">
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.new">
    </div>
</div>
```

if i use **new** instead of **$parent.new** i get undefined, but when i use $parent.new and i write in one input, it also writes in other inputs.[image]

Comment: This is because you're binding every input to the same model with ngModel.

Comment: and how to make correct ? i have divs generated by ng-repeat according how many news i have in array. and one input inside each div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are assigning all of the inputs to the same model, so your inputs are all in sync with the same object.

What you need is to assign each input to a different model. I'm guessing you need these models to be dynamic, so you should use an array as your model and track your `ng-repeat` by `$index` like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="comments in articles track by $index">
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="arr[$index]">
        <span ng-if="arr[$index]">
            {{arr[$index]}}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, in your controller, you can initialize the empty `arr` like so:

```
$scope.arr = [];
```

Now, your inputs will be in sync with `$scope.arr` depending on the index they were in.

Try out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2scqao1s/) for an example.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you are happy with the answer, close the question by selecting this as the answer.

Comment: I want to apply same thing for edit.I have three text boxes.After clicking edit for second textbox i want to display value related to second text box.But now it is displaying in all text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've giving same `model` (`ng-model="$parent.new"`) for all of the `inputs` What you should do to avoid this problem is assign different `model` to each input element. Something like

```
<div class="comments" ng-repeat="articles in [1,2,[4,5,6]]">
<div ng-repeat="comments in articles">
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="comments">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Changed the code a little. Yes, and what should i do ? let say i have 3 divs with some information and input for inside each of them. i want to write comment on first div. how to make this ?

Comment: now you `comments` in your `article` array will be modeled to this value.

Comment: and how to access via scope ? because in this case $scope.comments is undefined

Comment: `$scope.articles.comments`

Answer (score 0):

Change ng-model of input to

```
<input type="text" ng-model="comments.comment">
```